# Expanding UITableViewCell UIElements Constraint Issues?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, constraints

After an extended amount of time searching for an answer and fidgeting within my project, I have decided to come here.

The issue: I have created a UITableView in which the cells expand when a user taps on them. This part is perfect, however, I can not seem to get either the constraints or heights correct. The cells are each 1/3 of the TOTAL screen (including status & navigation bar) before they are tapped, and then they expand to be 1.75 times that size. Originally there is just a UIImageView that takes up the unrevealed cell and once it is taped it is supposed to reveal a UIScrollView (of which contains static data.) However, I can not seem to get this to happen, when I add constrains I either get overlapping ImageViews that opens to a part of the ScrollView, squished images, or a properly working expanding cell but once the cell opens the image expands with it (which I do not mind) but the ScrollView is not there.

I have attached a screenshot of a reconstruction of the interface builder. The UIImageView is set to 300, the ScrollView to 215. [Screenshot of Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K72rp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check content hugging priority and content compression resistance priority of your image view and scrollView.

Comment: well you wrote " when I add constrains". I am assuming you are adding them runtime but I don't see the code for this. Use view debugging to determine where is the scroll view, when you don't see it and what are the constraints when ImageView overlaps scroll view.
Also you might want to present tableView with already expanded cells to make sure approach that you are trying to make dynamic actually works.

Answer (score 0):

```
func checkHeight() {

levelsView.hidden = (frame.size.height < P1Cell.expandedHeight)}
```

you should check this return no or yes,
and how about change frame to bounds.